# How to get a thank you after the completion of the form?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am trying to get a "thank you" message instead of a form that I have created on HTML. I want to get a thank you message only if the user has submitted all their details and everything.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class = "form">
        <form>
            <!-- Name -->
            <label class = "firstName">First name</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder = "John" required = "required" pattern="[A-Za-z].         {1,20}" id = "firstName"><br>
            <label class = "lastName">Last name</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder = "AppleSeed" required = "required" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id = "lastName"><br>
            <!-- Email -->
            <label class = "email">Email</label><br>
            <input type= "email" placeholder = "j.appleseed@example.co.uk" size = "42" required = "required" id = "email"><br>
            <!-- Mobile Number -->
            <label class = "tel">Mobile Number</label><br>
            <input placeholder = "Your Mobile Number" size = "42" required = "required" pattern="[0-9]{6,13}" id = "number"><br><br>
            <!-- The Submit button -->
            <button class = "submit" onclick="revealMessage()">
                <span title="What are you waiting for? Click it!">Submit</span>
            </button>
            <h1 id = "hiddenMessage" style = "display: none">Thank You!</h1>
        </form>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function revealMessage()
    {
    document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("form").style.display = "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. getElementsByClassName is plural. You need to add [0] to the result or better, don't use it
2. You want to access the submit event - just hiding the form when clicking the button, will not submit the form and also not trigger the validation
3. You had a bug in your pattern for the First name too
4. When you hide the form div, the content will hide too
5. You may want to use AJAX since the form removes the page when submitting - with Ajax you can return thank you from the server

Anyway this shows the thankyou before submitting when things are filled correctly. the HTML5 required and the pattern will not allow submission until correctly filled

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // pause submission
  document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("formDiv").style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.submit()
  }, 2000)
})
```

```html
<div class="form" id="formDiv">
  <form id="myForm">
    <!-- Name -->
    <label class="firstName">First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="firstName"><br>
    <label class="lastName">Last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="AppleSeed" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="lastName"><br>
    <!-- Email -->
    <label class="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="j.appleseed@example.co.uk" size="42" required="required" id="email"><br>
    <!-- Mobile Number -->
    <label class="tel">Mobile Number</label><br>
    <input placeholder="Your Mobile Number" size="42" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{6,13}" id="number"><br><br>
    <!-- The Submit button -->
    <button type="submit" class="submit">
                <span title="What are you waiting for? Click it!">Submit</span>
            </button>
  </form>
</div>
<h1 id="hiddenMessage" style="display: none">Thank You!</h1>
```

Comment: Hey! I tried to implement the code you gave and while it does ask me to write all the things in the form, when I press submit after writing all the things, the page just reloads and I don't get a 'thank you' message.

Comment: Sorry, I did not move your H1 outside the DIV. I now let the user see the message for 2 seconds bfore actually submitting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form").style.display = "none";
```

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector(".form").style.display = "none";
```

Also, move your `hiddenMessage` div outside of your form so it doesn't get hidden with the form on submit.

See the snippet below:

```js
function revealMessage() {
  document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(".form").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form onsubmit="revealMessage()">
    <!-- Name -->
    <label class="firstName">First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John" pattern="[A-Za-z].         {1,20}" id="firstName" required><br>
    <label class="lastName">Last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="AppleSeed" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="lastName" required><br>
    <!-- Email -->
    <label class="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="j.appleseed@example.co.uk" size="42" id="email" required><br>
    <!-- Mobile Number -->
    <label class="tel">Mobile Number</label><br>
    <input placeholder="Your Mobile Number" size="42" pattern="[0-9]{6,13}" id="number" required><br><br>
    <!-- The Submit button -->
    <button type="submit" class="submit">
                <span title="What are you waiting for? Click it!">Submit</span>
            </button>

  </form>
</div>

<h1 id="hiddenMessage" style="display: none">Thank You!</h1>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. But, the problem with that is that even if the user doesn't put in all the required information in the form, the form gets submitted and you get a thank you. What I want is that if the forms are filled in the pattern given in the HTML, it should then get submitted. Thanks again.

Comment: Your code does not submit the form at all. It just hides it

Comment: See my updated snippet. If you want your required fields to work then run your revealMessage function `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: https://noll-demo.squarespace.com/consultations This is a type of thing I want to implement in my code. When I press submit on this page, it hides the form and says thank you but only if I have given all the details

Comment: The updated code will work just like that.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit

There is an event Called onsubmit on javascript when you submit you can alert or do what ever suits `you`

```html
<div class="form">
  <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <!-- Name -->
    <label class="firstName">First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John" required="required" id="firstName"><br>
    <label class="lastName">Last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="AppleSeed" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="lastName"><br>
    <!-- Email -->
    <label class="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="j.appleseed@example.co.uk" size="42" required="required" id="email"><br>
    <!-- Mobile Number -->
    <label class="tel">Mobile Number</label><br>
    <input placeholder="Your Mobile Number" size="42" required="required" id="number"><br><br>
    <!-- The Submit button -->
    <button class="submit">
                <span title="What are you waiting for? Click it!">Submit</span>
            </button>

  </form>
</div>

<h1 id="hiddenMessage" style="display: none">Thank You!</h1>

<script>


function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Please either expand on this, into an answer... Or less preferable leave this as a comment. As it really isn't a full answer at current.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. But, the problem with that is that even if the user doesn't put in all the required information in the form, the form gets submitted and you get a thank you. What I want is that if the forms are filled in the pattern given in the HTML, it should then get submitted. Thanks again.